# Classnotfound exception when running java applet

Tags: java, applet, noclassdeffounderror

Having problem to run applet in server.My applet script is

```
<?php

echo 'Signature:: <p  align="center"> <applet code="draw1/DrawApplet.class" codebase="draw1/DrawApplet.java"
        width="'.$apWidth.'" height="'.$apHeight.'" id="'.$formID.'">
       <PARAM NAME="BAH" VALUE="10">
       <PARAM NAME="id" VALUE="10">
       <PARAM NAME="type" VALUE="Sig">
       <PARAM NAME="server" VALUE="'.$importantData['SignatureSavingAddress'].'">
       <PARAM NAME="java_arguments" VALUE="-Djnlp.packEnabled=false">
     </applet> </p></form></div>';?>
```

and here is the java code

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;


import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import java.lang.*;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import java.util.Calendar;

import java.awt.AWTEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.*;

import java.awt.MouseInfo;

public class DrawApplet extends JApplet implements ActionListener , MouseListener
{
    public static final String DATE_FORMAT_NOW = "yyyy.MM.dd'_'HH.mm.ss.SSS";
    public static final SimpleDateFormat dataFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT_NOW);

    public String SERVER = "https://www.physicianxpress.net/DOM/draw1/upload.php";
    public static final String CLEAR_STRING = "Clear";
    public static final String SAVE_STRING = "Save";
    public static final String STARTER_STRING = "Start";

    protected DrawPanel drawPanel;
        protected JButton save = new JButton(SAVE_STRING);
    protected JButton clear = new JButton(CLEAR_STRING);
    protected JButton starter = new JButton(STARTER_STRING);

        protected JLabel labeler = new JLabel("Please click the attach button below now.");

        protected JPanel center = new JPanel();


        public int curX, curY;


    //Called when this applet is loaded into the browser.
    public void init()
    {
        String tempServer   = getParameter("server");
        SERVER = tempServer + "/DOM/draw1/upload.php";

            //JButton clear = new JButton(CLEAR_STRING);
        clear.setActionCommand(CLEAR_STRING);
        clear.addActionListener(this);

                starter.setActionCommand(STARTER_STRING);
        starter.addActionListener(this);

        //JButton save = new JButton(SAVE_STRING);
        save.setActionCommand(SAVE_STRING);
        save.addActionListener(this);
        save.setMnemonic('s');

                JPanel mid = new JPanel();

                JPanel east2 = new JPanel();
                east2.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

                JPanel east = new JPanel();
                east.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        //east.add(BorderLayout.NORTH, starter); //
        east.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, clear); //
        east.add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, save); //

                east2.add(BorderLayout.NORTH, east); //
                east2.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, mid); //

        drawPanel = new DrawPanel();

        //JPanel center = new JPanel();
        center.setLayout(new BoxLayout(center, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        center.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLoweredBevelBorder());
        center.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        center.add(drawPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        add(center, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(east2, BorderLayout.EAST);
        add(labeler , BorderLayout.SOUTH);


                //labeler.setHorizontalTextPosition(1);
                labeler.setBackground(Color.yellow);
                labeler.setVisible(false);
                drawPanel.setEnabled(false);


                // be compatible for a mouse listener.
                //enableEvents(AWTEvent.MOUSE_MOTION_EVENT_MASK | AWTEvent.MOUSE_EVENT_MASK);

                //starter.addMouseListener(this);
                //drawPanel.addMouseListener(this);

                //addMouseListener(this);

        String tempID = getParameter("id");

        if(tempID == null || tempID.length() <= 0)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Please reload, your signature will not attach properly.", "Success", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        }
    }

    public void start()
    {

    }

    public void stop()
    {

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getActionCommand().equals(CLEAR_STRING))
        {
            drawPanel.clear();
        }
                else if(e.getActionCommand().equals(STARTER_STRING))
                {
                    // lock the cursor into the box.

                    // set everything to true.
                    center.setVisible(true);
                    clear.setVisible(true);
                    save.setVisible(true);

                    drawPanel.setEnabled(true);
                    drawPanel.clear();      // clear it.


                    drawPanel.setXPos(curX);
                    drawPanel.setYPos(curY);

                    System.out.println("Set Positions.");
                    starter.setVisible(false);
                    starter.setEnabled(false);

                }
        else if(e.getActionCommand().equals(SAVE_STRING))
        {
            Image image = drawPanel.getImage();

            BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(drawPanel.getWidth(), drawPanel.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
            Graphics graphics = bufferedImage.createGraphics();
            graphics.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);

            try
            {
                                double randNumber = Math.random();

                //ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "jpg", new java.io.File("new_abc.jpg"));
                ImageUploader.sendData(SERVER, getFileName() + "_"+randNumber+".jpg", (Image)bufferedImage);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Image Uploaded, please attach it by clicking the button below.", "Success", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

                                drawPanel.clear();

                                center.setVisible(false);
                                clear.setVisible(false);
                                starter.setVisible(false);
                                save.setVisible(false);
                                labeler.setVisible(true);
                                drawPanel.setVisible(false);

                                //drawPanel.resize(new Dimension(400,30));
                                this.resize(new Dimension(400,30));
                                //repaint();

            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Unable To Upload Image:" + ex.getMessage(), "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            //ImageIO.write(image, String formatName, null);    
        }   
    }

    private String getFileName()
    {
        //Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        //return dataFormat.format(cal.getTime());
        String fileName   = getParameter("id");
                  return fileName;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        DrawApplet drawApplet = new DrawApplet();
        drawApplet.setSize(400, 200);
        drawApplet.setVisible(true);
    }

           public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        //     System.out.println("Mouse pressed; # of clicks: " + e.getClickCount());
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
       //System.out.println("Mouse released; # of clicks: "
       //             + e.getClickCount());
    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        try
        {
            //int x = e.getX();
            //int y = e.getY();

            int x = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x;
            int y = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y;

            curX = x;
            curY = y;

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            String s = "mouse entred error" + ex.toString();
            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, s, "Success", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
            //ex.printStackTrace();

        }
        System.out.println("Mouse entered: (" + curX + "," + curY + ")");

    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
       //System.out.println("Mouse exited");

        if(e.getSource()==drawPanel)
        {
            // suck it back into the object
            System.out.println("In the attempt to exit");
            try
            {
                int x = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x;
                int y = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y;

                System.out.println("Mouse Exit: (" + curX + "," + curY + ") - exitX: (" + x + "," + y + ")");
                try
                {
                    Robot rob = new Robot();
                    rob.mouseMove(curX, curY);
                }
                catch(Exception ex3)
                {
                    System.out.println("Exception in the exit: " + ex3.toString());
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                String s = "mouse entred error" + ex.toString();
                //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, s, "Success", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                //ex.printStackTrace();

            }

        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Not the source");
        }


    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
       //System.out.println("Mouse clicked (# of clicks: "
       //             + e.getClickCount() + ")");
    }

    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {

        try
        {
            int x = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x;
            int y = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y;

            curX = x;
            curY = y;

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            String s = "mouse entred error" + ex.toString();
            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, s, "Success", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
            //ex.printStackTrace();

        }

    }
```

I am totally new to java. Recently got a project to fix this bug. The bug here I need to fix is why the applet is not working. I have checked in IE and got classNotFoundException.

I have installed Java 8.

Can anyone please tell me which things I need to check to fix this bug.

Comment: Sorry that nobody told you yet: java applets are dead. Dead end technology. No browser runs them any more (at least not without getting into total headache). Unless somebody is paying you big money for doing this ... don't do it. Spend your learning time on something that has more value than "computer science history". Beyond that:

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the [edit] link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: Dont you think it matters **what** class isn't found?

Comment: @GhostCat  I have already mentioned that I am getting classNotFoundException error which caused this applet non functional,where the class path is correct. 
I want to know which things I need to check to debug this.

Comment: What class isn't found? Dont you think that matters? Stack trace?!

Comment: @GhostCat DrawApplet.class is not found

Comment: Yeah, so *whatever* you invoke to run java code, doesn't have that class in its class path. But that is the point: we have no idea what you are doing exactly. It would matter greatly for example what happens on the server that creates that page that you open in your browser ...